# Are environment variables preserved through qx in a perl script

Tags: perl, qx

I have some legacy perl script, which sets environment variable

```
$ENV{"ENV_VAR_NAME"} = $envVar;
```

and then uses qx() to execute another shell command

```
$command = "$xyz";
$result = qx($command);
```

Will the modified ENV_VAR_NAME be available when 
qx executes the new command.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I have multiple Scripts called in $command and somewhere i think the same Env variable seems to be overwritten. I was not sure if qx retains the env variable and hence thought of asking.

Comment: I see the problem that i had was different, i was executing the command on a remote system. So i have some thing like qx("ssh ...")... on localhost it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

[`perlvar`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25ENV) says about `%ENV`:

> Setting a value in ENV changes the environment for any child processes you subsequently fork() off.

And [`qx`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%60_STRING_%60) does indeed spawn a child process, which can therefore access your modified environment variables.

This can be easily tested:

```
print "1: ", qx(echo \$X); # Prints "1: "

$ENV{X} = 42;

print "2: ", qx(echo \$X); # Prints "2: 42"
```

Comment: I see the problem i had was different, i was executing the command on a remote system.